# How can I sort using MUI Datatable using value, instead of what's return by custom body render?

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I am working with MUI Datatables, I have a column that tells the number of users who visited a site. Till this point everything works fine but as soon as I use custom rendering to show the percentage of change, the sorting dramatically changes. I am pretty new to React but I have done quite a lot RnD on this issue but still nothing really worked.
Here's my code for column definition

```
  const topSitesColumnsComparison = [
  {
    label: "Site Name",
    key: "site",
    options: {
      customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <a className="card-url-color" href={tableMeta.rowData[1]}>
              {value}
            </a>
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  },
  {
    label: "Site URL",
    key: "siteurl",
    sort: false,
    options: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
  {
    label: "Visits",
    key: "visits",
    options: {
      sort: true,
      sortDirection: "desc",
      customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {tableMeta.rowData[3] < 0 ? (
              <div>
                <div style={{ display: "inline-block", minWidth: "45px" }}>
                  {value}{" "}
                </div>
                <span style={{ color: "#b80000", fontSize: "11px" }}>
                  {" "}
                  <FontIcon
                    style={{ verticalAlign: "bottom", fontSize: "11px" }}
                    iconName="StockDown"
                  ></FontIcon>{" "}
                  {Math.abs(Math.round(tableMeta.rowData[3] * 100) / 100)}%{" "}
                  <span></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                {tableMeta.rowData[3] == 0 ? (
                  <div style={{ display: "inline-block", minWidth: "45px" }}>
                    {value}{" "}
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div>
                    <div style={{ display: "inline-block", minWidth: "45px" }}>
                      {value}{" "}
                    </div>
                    <span style={{ color: "#0B6623", fontSize: "11px" }}>
                      {" "}
                      <FontIcon
                        style={{ verticalAlign: "bottom", fontSize: "11px" }}
                        iconName="StockUp"
                      ></FontIcon>{" "}
                      {Math.abs(Math.round(tableMeta.rowData[3] * 100) / 100)}%{" "}
                      <span></span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  },
  {
    label: "Change",
    key: "change",
    options: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
];
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

add name:site to sort by the mui column.
for sorting by the returned value of customBodyRender just return the value without any div.